# How to solve the "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Tags: mysql, asp.net, 64-bit, odbc, windows-8.1

I hade my website(ASP.NET 4.5) working with MySQL ODBC 5.1 but while having this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080505/server-does-not-support-4-byte-encoded-after-update I tried to install MySQL ODBC 5.3.4 and change the connection string from 5.1 to 5.3. Now I got the `ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified` exception that many others have hade.

Anyway, I uninstalled 5.3 and 5.1 and then installed 5.1 64 bit go my Windows 8.1 64 but I still gets the same exception!? I tried restart and uninstall/install again but it throws the same exception.

I have tried to add the driver(pointing out the server) in the Controlpanel > ODBC Data Source 64 > System DSN but it does still not work.

Edit : I can connect and work with the database with the MySQl Workbench without problems.

Exact exception : `ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

This is the current connectionstring :

```
<add name="MySite" connectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=3306;DATABASE=195414-MySite;USER=[myuser];PASSWORD=[mypassword] OPTION=3"/>
```

The Server is set to 127.0.0.1 becouse Im using SSH and this have worked fine before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to uninstall all mySQL ODBC drivers and then installthe 32 bit 5.1 and that worked fine! It did however still not work with the 5.3 32 bit.